# Upgrade MacbookPro (15' mid 2010), beyond 8G RAM

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, memory

Som there are a couple of past questions with answers on this topic here and the bigger interwebs. My reason for re-opening this issue is that most answers are from around 2013 - 2015 latest. So I am wondering if there has been an update since.

early apple forum that claims success of 16RAM on mid 2010, 15' when booting in safe mode:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2763468?start=105&tstart=0

comments claim that upgrade to 16G RAM was a success (end 2015):
https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/148841/16+GB+possible+with+OS+X+Mountain+Lion+or+Mavericks

last answer claims that the only way to do this is by installing linux:
https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/151681/I'm+experiencing+random+kernel+panics

Mid 2010 can go up to 12G RAM:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/214900/223701

I would really, REALLY like to use 16Gb RAM since my computing demands are quite high. Anybody have any definitive stories? Thanks!

Comment: Probably no more definitive than what you've already seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not alone in your confusion, and there's four good reasons for it:

- Some MacBooks can only use Apple's "official" maximum RAM
- Other MacBooks can actually use more (usually twice as much)
- Newer MacBooks have their RAM soldered in and cannot be upgraded after being purchased
- The answer differs depending on the model of mid-2010 MacBook Pro!

You were probably aware of the first three reasons, but the last one often catches people out. To clarify this:

- 13" mid-2010 MacBook Pro models **can** actually use 16GB RAM
- 15" mid-2010 MacBook Pro models **cannot** use 16GB RAM
- 17" mid-2010 MacBook Pro models **cannot** use 16GB RAM

Unfortunately, this means for you the answer is **no**.

Comment: what is fascinating to me, is that apparently when a 16GB RAM update is performed on a mid 2010, 15", it works given that it runs on Linux. This would suggest that there is no **machine** level constraint. However, my hope was that anybody had tried this experiment with newer OS to confirm that apple at no point updated for this potential awesome upgrade. Will wait 2/3 more days to give other people a chance to prove me wrong, else i'm afraid i'll have to check your answer :(